# Win32 ReadFile() refuses to read more than 16Mb at once?

Tags: c, winapi, readfile

I've got very strange problem on my Windows XP in VirtualBox.

`ReadFile()` function refuses to read more than 16Mb of data in single call.
It returns error code 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT`).
Looks like data length is limited to 24 bits.

Here is the example code allowed me to find out exact limit.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int fd,len,readed;
    char *buffer;
    char *fname="Z:\\test.dat";
    fd=_open(fname,_O_RDWR|_O_BINARY,_S_IREAD|_S_IWRITE);
    if (fd==-1) {
        printf("Error opening file : %s\n",strerror(errno));
        getch();
        return -1;
    }
    len=_lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    _lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    if (!len) {
        printf("File length is 0.\n");
        getch();
        return -2;
    }
    buffer=(char *)malloc(len);
    if (!buffer) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        getch();
        return -3;
    }
    readed=0;
    while (readed<len) {
        len-=100;
        readed=_read(fd,buffer,len);
        if (len<=100) break;
    }
    if (readed!=len) {
        printf("Failed to read file: result %d error %s\n",readed,strerror(errno));
        getch();
        return -4;
    }
    _close(fd);
    printf("Success (%u).",len);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

File `Z:\test.dat` length is 21Mb.

Result is "`Success (16777200).`"

I was trying to find same issues in Google without any success :(

May be someone knows what is the cause of the problem?

Comment: If the file is only 21 megabits (about 2.6MB), how can you succeed in reading 16777200 bytes?

Comment: I'm puzzled that the description talks about `ReadFile()` and the code uses `_read()`.  What's the connection between these two names?

Comment: if you will trace ReadFile(), it is calling _read() to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with `ReadFile()` itself.  The real problem is that your `while()` loop is buggy to begin with.  You are mismanaging the `len` and `readed` variables.  On each iteration of the loop, you decrement `len` and reset `readed`.  Eventually, `len` is decremented to a value that matches `readed` and the loop stops running.  The fact that your "Success" message reports 16MB is coincidence, because you are modifying both variables while you read the file.  `len` is initially set to 21MB and counts down until `_read()` happens to return a 16MB buffer when 16MB was asked for.  That does not mean that `ReadFile()` failed on a 16MB read (if that were the case, the very first loop iteration would fail because it asks for a 21MB read).

You need to fix your `while()` loop, not blame `ReadFile()`.  The correct looping logic should look more like this instead:

```
int total = 0; 

while (total < len)
{ 
    readed = _read(fd, &buffer[total], len-total); 
    if (readed < 1) break;
    total += readed;
} 

_close(fd); 

if (total != len)
{ 
    printf("Failed to read file: %d out of %d, error %s\n", total, len, strerror(errno)); 
    ...
    return -4; 
} 

printf("Success (%u).",total); 
...
```

Comment: Or `buffer + total` instead of `&buffer[total]`, but this logic looks MUCH better.

Comment: The compiler will generally output the same machine code for `buffer + total` and `&buffer[total]`. So it is more a matter of personal coding style.

Comment: You did not read my question :( That loop aint supposed to read all the file in a loop. That loop is finding out maximal block size what ReadFile() reads without errors. 
First, it tries to read all file in one chunk - 21 Mb. ReadFile() returns an error. Then it tries to read 100 bytes lesser block. ReadFile() still returns an error. And so on, it stops when ReadFile() returns success.
And this is NOT read error or something... ReadFile() does not try to read the file at all, it just returns ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT if block size is more than 16Mb.

Comment: I agree with Hans then. When testing your code in a non-virtual XP SP2 environment with a 600MB test file, the first call to _read() was able to return the entire 600MB in a single read (well, 600MB - 100b since you decrement the len before performing the first read) without any error. So it is definately likely that your VirtualBox system is limiting the size you can use for the buffer.

Comment: Yes I think so. But I still wonder, why VirtualBox does so.

Comment: Does it really matter why?  It is happening.  ReadFile() (and consequently _read()) is allowed to return less than the number of bytes requested, so you have to take the actual return value into account correctly when reading data.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely legal for a device driver to return less bytes than requested.  That's why ReadFile() has the lpNumberOfBytesRead argument.  You should avoid the low-level CRT implementation details, like _read().  Use fread() instead.

Update: this isn't the correct answer.  It looks like your virtual machine simply refuses to consider ReadFile() calls that ask for more than 16MB.  Probably has something to do with an internal buffer it uses to talk to the host operating system.  Nothing you can do but call fread() in a loop so you can stay below this upper limit.

Comment: ReadFile() returns -1.
It does not read anything if supplied nNumberOfBytesRead is greater than 16Mb.
Error code is ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT.

Comment: Okay, it's allowed to bitch about that as well.  Use fread().

Comment: just replaced _read() and so with f*(). Same issue.

Comment: I even tried to use fread(buffer,len/2,2,f) - it still fails for len>16Mb.

Comment: What is the runtime environment like?  Who created the CRT?  You probably will have to punt this and call fread() for partial reads in a loop.

Comment: I've traced fread() and _read() calls to ReadFile() call. So the problem definitely not in CRT. It is WinAPI function what returns this error. fread() and _read() are just wrappers for this ReadFile() call.
Yes I'm going to apply this little 'hack' and split file to smaller blocks. But I'm still curious about the cause of the problem.

Comment: The cause of the problem has nothing to do with ReadFile() itself.  The looping code is buggy to begin with.  See my other answer.

Comment: Commented your answer, you didn't read my question :(

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx). (see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556.aspx). The following simple code shows one way to do this:

```
LPCTSTR pszSrcFilename = TEXT("Z:\\test.dat");
HANDLE hSrcFile = CreateFile (pszSrcFilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                              NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                              NULL);
HANDLE hMapSrcFile = CreateFileMapping (hSrcFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
PBYTE pSrcFile = (PBYTE) MapViewOfFile (hMapSrcFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
DWORD dwInFileSizeHigh, dwInFileSizeLow;
dwInFileSizeLow = GetFileSize (hInFile, &dwInFileSizeHigh);
```

After some simple steps you have a pointer `pSrcFile` which represent **the whole file contents**. Is this not what you need? The total size of the memory block in stored in  `dwInFileSizeHigh` and `dwInFileSizeLow`: `((__int64)dwInFileSizeHigh << 32)+dwInFileSizeLow`.

This uses the same feature of the Windows kernel that is used to implement the swap file (page file). It is buffered by the disk cache and very efficient. If plan to access the file mostly sequentially, including the flag FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN in the call to `CreateFile()` will hint this fact to the system, causing it to try to read ahead for even better performance.

I see that file which you read in the test example has the name "Z:\test.dat". If it is a file coming from a network drive you will see a clear performance advantage. Morover corresponds with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366542.aspx you hav the limit about 2 GB instead of 16Mb. I recommend you to map files till 1 GB and then just create a net view with respect of `MapViewOfFile` (I am not sure that you code need work with so large files). More then that, on the same MSDN page you can read following

> The size of the file mapping object
>   that you select controls how far into
>   the file you can "see" with memory
>   mapping. If you create a file mapping
>   object that is 500 Kb in size, you
>   have access only to the first 500 Kb
>   of the file, regardless of the size of
>   the file. Since it does not cost you
>   any system resources to create a
>   larger file mapping object, create a
>   file mapping object that is the size
>   of the file (set the `dwMaximumSizeHigh`
>   and `dwMaximumSizeLow` parameters of
>   `CreateFileMapping` both to zero) even
>   if you do not expect to view the
>   entire file. The cost in system
>   resources comes in creating the views
>   and accessing them.

So the usage of memory mapped files is really cheap. If your program reads only portions of the file contents skipping large parts of the file, then you will also have a large performance advantage because it will read only the parts of file which you really accessed (rounded to 16K pages).

More clean code for for file mapping is following

```
DWORD MapFileInMemory (LPCTSTR pszFileName,
                       PBYTE *ppbyFile,
                       PDWORD pdwFileSizeLow, OUT PDWORD pdwFileSizeHigh)
{
    HANDLE  hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, hFileMapping = NULL;
    DWORD dwStatus = NO_ERROR;
    const DWORD dwSourceId = MSG_SOURCE_MAP_FILE_IN_MEMORY;

    __try {
        hFile = CreateFile (pszFileName, FILE_READ_DATA, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                            NULL);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            __leave;
        }

        *pdwFileSizeLow = GetFileSize (hFile, pdwFileSizeHigh);
        if (*pdwFileSizeLow == INVALID_FILE_SIZE){
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            __leave;
        }

        hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping (hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
        if (!hFileMapping){
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            __leave;
        }

        *ppbyFile = (PBYTE) MapViewOfFile (hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
        if (*ppbyFile == NULL) {
            dwStatus = GetLastError();
            __leave;
        }
    }
    __finally {
        if (hFileMapping) CloseHandle (hFileMapping);
        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) CloseHandle (hFile);
    }

    return dwStatus;
}

BOOL UnmapFileFromMemory (LPCVOID lpBaseAddress)
{
    return UnmapViewOfFile (lpBaseAddress);
}
```

Comment: MMF has pros and cons - cons include: on 32bit you have the problem of address space which severely limits how big files you can map (of course you can map "windows" into your file, but then you lose most of the MMF advantages). On both 32 and 64bit, you must keep in mind that mapping requires additional memory for the pagetable mappings. You have less control of caching. You generate a #PF hardware exception for each 4kb page you access (not a problem on today's CPUs, but it's overhead nonetheless).

Comment: @snemarch: The #PF hardware exception is the most optimized Windows code. At least this say MS. All costs for MMF together are less then a standard input/output operations. Of the file is very large one need of cause mapping of a part of file. Nevertheless because MMF is the most quickly access to files under Windows I'll use MMF also in this case. If you access to files from the network a simple experiment will show how much will be performance advantage of MMF. Just try it.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, but this is not what I'm asking for. I've already fixed this issue by reading file sequentially by 16Mb chunks. But I'm still curious about the cause of the problem described.
The problem is:
if I call ReadFile() with size argument greater than 16Mb, it fails with ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT result. 
This drive is not network drive, it is VirtualBox's shared folder.

Comment: I don't know about any restriction in `ReadFile`, but your goal is not to use one or another API. I understood, that you want to work with the full contain of the file having it as block of memory. If you write the program for Windows, then the best implementation of this requirement is the usage of memory-mapped files. Just compare performance of your program in case of usage any Read File function and `MapFileInMemory` function which I posted. You will see why I make the recomendation. If your program is started or it load DLL, exactly the same code will be used: memory mapping are created.

Comment: @Oleg: yes, #PF is optimized and you won't see much of a CPU hit unless you run on really low-end hardware... but you do get a #PF for each page access, and there will be more r3<>r0 transitions - and you aren't able to control buffering strategies. Whether MMF is the optimal access strategy depends on your usage patterns - if you read a lot from the same areas, being able to serve requests directly out of the buffer cache is nice. If you do huge one-pass data processing, it can be advantageous to unbuffered ReadFile to avoid using memory on useless buffering.

Comment: @snemarch: Sorry but I disagree with your. In `CreateFile` flags you can define the buffering strategies through flags. Any disk operations will be implemented with respect of hardware interrupts. A part of work will be made in user more, a part in kernel mode. #PF are the shortest and the most optimized I/O operation. So you not believe just make a test. In the question one read the file in the memory buffer to work with file as with memory block. For example use the program from the question to calculate MD5 of a file and repeat with the code which I posted. The results give you the answer.

Comment: I did a quick little test on 64bit Win7 w/8GB ram: mapping a ~3.2GB file makes the process' private bytes rise by around ~7MB. Touching the mapped memory makes commit charge rise by, surprise surprise, ~3.2GB. Finally, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is only partially honored - if specified it *does* force re-reading, but if removed a second sum takes a few seconds, so obviously the file *is* cached.

Comment: @snemarch: Sorry but I can not follow you. Which connection has your experiments to the question asked by mephisto123? What do want to show with your experiments? Correspond to the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366542.aspx which I inserted in my answer you can safe use till "2 GB minus the virtual memory already reserved by the process". You can effective use file-mapping of very large files, can use SEC_LARGE_PAGES, map not the whole file at once and so on. But all this is another question. Could you see that MMF work very good with files 25MB like it was in **the question**?

Comment: @oleg: all I'm trying to say is that MMF isn't the end-all-be-all solution to file access, and that it has some downsides. If you work with huge files on 32bit systems and thus need windowed access, you lose one of the biggest benefits of MMF, "the file is just one memory area". SEC_LARGE_PAGES only works for pagefile-backed MMF (ie., not for file access). As for topic relevance, MMF isn't very relevant to what's probably a driver bug/limit in VirtualBox :) PS: 16K pages? That'd be 4K pages or 64K allocation-granularity size :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume, Z: in your example is a shared folder. I just stumbled upon the same bug, and spent some time trying to pin it down.

It seems, the problem has been known for a while: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5830.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a limitation in Windows. According to my experience, on Windows XP and 2003 x86 and x64, `ReadFile()` fails to read more than 16 MB. On Windows 2008 r2 and Windows 8 x64 the threshold is much higher > 1 GB. I am using unbuffered IO for a backup utility.

I have never used `MMF`, but ReadFile and WriteFile are extremely fast with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. And the CPU usage* is almost 0 while reading at 147 MB/s.

Intel i7

Comment: This issue is not related to Windows. It is related to VirtualBox.

Comment: @mephisto123, this limitation is in effect, no matter whether the OS is running virtualized or not.

Comment: No, it is not in effect without VirtualBox.